# What is the Address Format of XMPP?

Tags: xmpp

If I type "netstat -an" on CMD how can I tell what connections are based off messaging services - particularly XMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the XMPP servers that a connection has been made to are using the standard ports, you can filter on the following ports:

```
5222 TCP     XMPP client connection (RFC 3920)        Official  
5223 TCP     XMPP client connection over SSL          Unofficial
5269 TCP     XMPP server connection (RFC 3920)        Official
5298 TCP UDP XMPP JEP-0174: Link-Local Messaging /    Official
         XEP-0174: Serverless Messaging
8010 TCP     XMPP File transfers                      Unofficial
```

Apart from that you cannot determine what connection is being used by which protocol by looking at TCP connections. You would have to sniff the connections by using a packet sniffer (Wireshark). Wireshark does contain filters for protocols.